# Ensuring "Always Check for new Pages" in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, group-policy

We are having a problem with some of our web services in our applications.  Basically, Internet Explorer is caching some of the XML and so the apps are not updating.  I have been asked by some of our developers to see if there is a way, either via vbscript that I can add to the login script or through Group Policy, to ensure that the setting:

Internet Options -> General -> Browsing History -> Settings -> Check for newer versions of stored pages

is set to Everytime I visit the webpage.

I have been unsuccessful so far to find a way to manipulate this through script or through modifying a registry key.  Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.  I need to cover IE 6,7, & 8 preferably.

Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Comment: You should change the cache headers on the server.

Comment: An alternative workaround would be to add a random string to the redirect url after login.

Comment: The site is hosted by a third party.  How would I request that to them?  Thanks.

Comment: Is it your content on someone else's server or is it a site you have absolutely no control over ? If it is your content, generated dynamically you can set the expiry date yourself (e.g System.Web.HttpResponse.ExpiresAbsolute for .NET and Response.ExpiresAbsolute for classic ASP

Answer (score 1):

The registry key is named SyncMode5, you'll find it in: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

You can also configure this setting using the IEAK.

But Slaks is correct that the proper fix is to have the server send correct caching headers.